# Splinter childnodes div

Tags: css-selectors, nodes, splinter

I'm using Splinter (https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for web testing, I successfully fetch the div element by using browser.find_by_css(), the div contains child nodes. I'm using phantomjs driver.

How can I access the child nodes of the div represented by a WebDriver object
returned by browser.find_by_css()?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand exactly what you need, but it may be one of those:

```
value = browser.find_by_css('h1')

print value.first
print value[4] (for forth child)
```